# How to find inner of node with xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have a hierarchy like that :

```
<div>
    <a>Title</a>
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

i have to list with this xpath code : "//a", and div node is dynamic so it's may be tr or p... I want to find img tag via a tag. How do i do that?

I have tried "//a/ancestor::*//img" but it's not working.

Comment: `//a/following-sibling::img`. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=following-sibling

Comment: Thank you Wrikken for your answer. My question is missing about tags, for example maybe "a" tag will be in another tag. Hierarchy of this situation :
<div>
    <h1><a>Title</a></h1>
    <img src="...">
</div>

Can i use following-sibling, in this situation?

Comment: Not `following-sibling`. `following::a` maybe, but that just means _'somwhere later in the document'_, which can be in a wildly different place. Having a definition on where a match is a match or not helps to contain it a little.

Answer (score -2):

You can (almost) treat XPath queries like a file system with directories. Every layer of nested tags is another "directory" in that filesystem, so

```
//a/../img
```

would find all `a` tags in the DOM, which are followed by an `img`. And the query would return those img tags. If you actually needed to deal with the `a` tag, but only those that have an `img` as a sibling, then it'd be a somewhat more complicated query.